# JQuery Watermark Plugin Submitting Watermarks As Values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, watermark

I am using the jquery.watermark.min.js plugin.

I just recently noticed that it is submitting the watermarks on form submit.  It wasn't doing it before, but now it is.  Not sure what I changed.  Any ideas? Or fixes?

I am using MVC, Ajax.BeginForm, I have a viewmodel with validation on it.

The website said something about using jquery validate and to activate it after the watermarks.  Is mvc doing something for me thats breaking this?

I just need some help moving past this...Thanks =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out an alternative, [the labelOver plugin](http://remysharp.com/2007/03/19/a-few-more-jquery-plugins-crop-labelover-and-pluck/) ([demo here](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/label_over_example.html)) which doesn't put the watermark in the inputs as values, but styles them to be placed on top...completely eliminating the issue, instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to hear. I was thinking of making exactly that. =D

Answer (score 0):

I have just get it solved adding this line before the form validation:

$.watermark.hideAll();

Works on IE7 and IE8

Just try it.

Thanks for all anyway

Comment: What do you mean by this?? Where exactly do you put this?